# Getting absolute path of a file

Tags: c, unix, path, filesystems, absolute

How can I convert a relative path to an absolute path in C on Unix?
Is there a convenient system function for this?

On Windows there is a `GetFullPathName` function that does the job, but I didn't find something similar on Unix...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use [realpath()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/realpath.html).

> The `realpath()` function shall derive,
>   from the pathname pointed to by
>   `file_name`, an absolute pathname that
>   names the same file, whose resolution
>   does not involve '`.`', '`..`', or
>   symbolic links. The generated pathname
>   shall be stored as a null-terminated
>   string, up to a maximum of `{PATH_MAX}`
>   bytes, in the buffer pointed to by
>   `resolved_name`.
>
> If `resolved_name` is a null pointer,
>   the behavior of `realpath()` is
>   implementation-defined.

---

> The following example generates an
>   absolute pathname for the file
>   identified by the symlinkpath
>   argument. The generated pathname is
>   stored in the actualpath array.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
char *symlinkpath = "/tmp/symlink/file";
char actualpath [PATH_MAX+1];
char *ptr;


ptr = realpath(symlinkpath, actualpath);
```

Comment: The 'plus one' is not necessary, thuogh it won't do any harm.

Comment: `GetFullPathName` on Windows works for non-existant files as well. `realpath` requires the path to exist. This kind of sucks when you want to create a path or file.

Comment: The actual path contains the absolute path, but what does ptr contain?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: PATH_MAX is "The uniform system limit (if any) for the length of an entire file name", so excludes the terminating nul which is added by `realpath`. The +1 is therefore required.

Comment: @EML +1 is not required. From POSIX limits.h rationale: "IEEE PASC Interpretation 1003.1 #15 addressed the inconsistency in the standard with the definition of pathname and the description of {PATH_MAX}, allowing application developers to allocate either {PATH_MAX} or {PATH_MAX}+1 bytes. The inconsistency has been removed by correction to the {PATH_MAX} definition to include the null character. With this change, applications that previously allocated {PATH_MAX} bytes will continue to succeed."

Comment: @osvein - interesting - thanks. OTOH, there are presumably older systems that predate this interpretation, so not using +1 in those cases won't "continue to succeed", but will just fail. If you're writing new code to run across a range of systems, this sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @osvein [`PATH_MAX` does not have to exist at all](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/limits.h.html#tag_13_23_03_02):  "A definition of one of the symbolic constants in the following list **shall be omitted** from the <limits.h> header on specific implementations where the corresponding value is equal to or greater than the stated minimum, but where the value can vary depending on the file to which it is applied.  ..."  Systems like Linux that have variable maximum path lengths for different filesystem types shouldn't define `PATH_MAX`.

Answer (score 8):

Try `realpath()` in `stdlib.h`

```
char filename[] = "../../../../data/000000.jpg";
char* path = realpath(filename, NULL);
if(path == NULL){
    printf("cannot find file with name[%s]\n", filename);
} else{
    printf("path[%s]\n", path);
    free(path);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also a small path library [cwalk](https://github.com/likle/cwalk) which works cross-platform. It has [cwk_path_get_absolute](https://likle.github.io/cwalk/reference/cwk_path_get_absolute.html) to do that:

```
#include <cwalk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char buffer[FILENAME_MAX];

  cwk_path_get_absolute("/hello/there", "./world", buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  printf("The absolute path is: %s", buffer);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Outputs:

```
The absolute path is: /hello/there/world
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try "getcwd"

```
#include <unistd.h>

char cwd[100000];
getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
std::cout << "Absolute path: "<< cwd << "/" << __FILE__ << std::endl;
```

Result:

```
Absolute path: /media/setivolkylany/WorkDisk/Programming/Sources/MichailFlenov/main.cpp
```

Testing environment:

```
setivolkylany@localhost$/ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
setivolkylany@localhost$/ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
setivolkylany@localhost$/ g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: 100K for a path?! surely 5K is enough? or PATH_MAX?

Comment: .... as [`getcwd`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) resolves the current working directory that code will likely fail for `__FILE__` of "/some/file/compiled/with/absolute.name`

Answer (score 0):

In case `realpath()` is not present (this is in case of windows), use [`_fullpath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fullpath-wfullpath?view=msvc-170).

Comment: If you are on Windows, you *have* `GetFullPathName` (as the question from 2008 mentions). Also, in 2023 you might want to use the standard library's [filesystem::absolute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/absolute)