# How to check if a path is a subdirectory of another path?

Tags: rust

I want to check if a path is a subdirectory of another path:

```rust
use std::path::Path;

let path = Path::new("/foo/bar/");
let child = Path::new("/foo/bar/baz");

assert_eq!(is_subdirectory(path, child), true);
```

How to do this?

Comment: [starts_with](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.starts_with)???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Path's method [starts_with](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.starts_with) works

```
use std::path::Path;

let path = Path::new("/foo/bar/");
let child = Path::new("/foo/bar/baz");

assert_eq!(child.starts_with(path), true);
assert_eq!(path.starts_with(child), false);
```

Comment: Note: this does not work with `PathBuf::from("./a/b").starts_with(&PathBuf::from("./c/../a"))` . You have to `canonicalize` first, which [introduce its own problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511331/getting-the-absolute-path-from-a-pathbuf).

Comment: @JasonLee that's kind of expected, `Path` is more like a string extension, it doesn't do computations around relative tokens `.`/`..`