# Deduce path from string input Rust

Tags: rust

I have a string input in the form "../../" or an alphabet like "a". I am passing the input to create_dir_all method to create a directory.I am looking for a way to deduce the path to the newly created directory from within Rust.

I have provided the example below.
Lets say, my current working directory is 'usr' whose path is $HOME/user/Desktop/usr. From this current path, I do,

```
fs::create_dir_all("../m")?;
```

This will create a directory one level above my current directory. The path to m would be $HOME/user/Desktop/m. I would like to save this path within my Rust program for later usage.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly, could try:

```
fs::canonicalize("../m")
```

[1] [Getting the absolute path from a PathBuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511331/getting-the-absolute-path-from-a-pathbuf)