# How to execute wxWidgets compiled file with double click?

Tags: c++, linux, build, wxwidgets

I build the wxWidgets library with the `--disable-shared` option and then compile the Hello-world sample code using:

```
g++ test_00.cpp `wx-config --libs --cxxflags --static=yes` -o test_00
```

The file is executable from terminal.  Then I run `chmod +x test_00` in the terminal.  However double clicking on that file gives me this error:

[image: img]

What can I do to make it executable with double click?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859895/execute-c-executable-by-double-click-on-linux-macos).  The file must be compiled using:

```
g++ test_00.cpp `wx-config --libs --cxxflags --static=yes` -o test_00 -no-pie
```

Afterwards, it is executable with double-click.  No `chmod` required.