# Loading texture won't work when providing relative path

Tags: c, macos, opengl, texture-mapping

I am running OS X 10.10.5. When I try to run (from the terminal) an OpenGL code that loads some textures, I get this error: "Cannot open file chair.bmp"
The error gets issued after executing this line

```
chairTexture = LoadTexBMP("chair.bmp");
```

providing a full path solves the problem but I need to make it work with a relative path.

The example code comes with a makefile:

```
    # Example 9
    EXE=ex9

    # Main target
    all: $(EXE)

    #  MinGW
    ifeq "$(OS)" "Windows_NT"
    CFLG=-O3 -Wall
    LIBS=-lglut32cu -lglu32 -lopengl32
    CLEAN=del *.exe *.o *.a
    else
    #  OSX
    ifeq "$(shell uname)" "Darwin"
    CFLG=-O3 -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations
    LIBS=-framework GLUT -framework OpenGL
    #  Linux/Unix/Solaris
    else
    CFLG=-O3 -Wall
    LIBS=-lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm
    endif
    #  OSX/Linux/Unix/Solaris
    CLEAN=rm -f $(EXE) *.o *.a
    endif

    # Compile rules
    .c.o:
        gcc -c $(CFLG) $<
    .cpp.o:
        g++ -c $(CFLG) $<

    #  Link
    ex9:ex9.o
        gcc -O3 -o $@ $^   $(LIBS)

    #  Clean
    clean:
        $(CLEAN)
```

running `pwd` in the terminal yields `/Users/nina/CG/ex9`

All texture images are in ex9 folder along with ex9.c and makefile. 
I tried to find a solution but all the solutions I found talks about changing the working directory in Xcode which I am not using.

Comment: try: chairTexture = LoadTexBMP("./chair.bmp");

Comment: @Murillio4 Already tried that, did not work.

Comment: have you tried to not use -O3? -O2 and -O3 does weird things to my programs somtimes

Comment: @Murillio4 do you mean removing all lines that has -O3 from the makefile?

Comment: while you are debugging, yes. When you use -O2 and -O3, the gcc compiler optimises your code output to make it faster.

Comment: @Murillio4 still won't work.

Comment: hm, you can get the full path dynamically by doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229012/getting-absolute-path-of-a-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured what I was doing wrong. I was using `open ex9` in the terminal which behaves as if I was clicking on the executable which in turns changes the working directory into the home directory. So, in order not to change the working directory I should use `./ex9`