# Get path from input to read a file

Tags: c, file, absolute-path

I would like to get a name of file from input and then read it. (Suppose that the file is in the directory of program.) To do that I need an absolute path. Please let me know how to achieve this goal using C.
This a part of my code:

```
scanf("%s",&filepath1);
FILE * fdw = fopen(filepath1, "a");
```

Comment: Remove the `&`.  You must not have it there, regardless of whether `filepath1` is a pointer or an array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229012/getting-absolute-path-of-a-file

Comment: What are you asking for?  If the user types an absolute path as the file name, then that's fine.  If the user types a relative name, you'll be able to use that too.  Do you want to convert a possibly relative name into an absolute path?  Which platform are you working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete the '&' symbol.

```
char filepath1[SIZE] = {0};

scanf("%s", filepath1);

FILE * fdw = fopen(filepath1, "a");
```