# Are there any alternatives to realpath()?

Tags: c

i was working on a project on my windows PC, which included the possibility to show the path of a file and I used the "realpath()" function... I executed it but the terminal returned this error to me...
`warning: implicit declaration of function 'realpath'` and also this one `` undefined reference to `realpath' `` with `collect2.exe: error ID returned 1 exit status`. Is there something to show the path of a file in C that works? Please help me I can't find the answer.

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229012/getting-absolute-path-of-a-file) the Windows function is `GetFullPathName()`

Comment: `realpath` is posix. Do you need a portable solution or Windows only ok?

Comment: [`GetFullPathName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfullpathnamea)

Comment: I was doing some tests, I developed this one on my Mac and it was working properly without errors, I opened it on my windows PC to have a .exe file but he couldn't even execute for this error, so yes, I was trying to give this executable to some of my friends but I can't.

Comment: I'm developing on C not C++, I saw that ```GetFullPathName``` but I can't use it I think

Comment: Why can you not use it?

Answer (score 2):

```
collect2.exe: error ID returned 1 exit status
```

It means that linker could not find the function `realpath` and did not link the program to produce the executable. I happened because Windows libraries do not have this function. You need to use `GetFullPathName()` function instead.

> I was trying to give this executable to some of my friends but I can't

It is because the .exe file was not created.

Comment: Can I also use it on C?

Comment: @Face._. yes you can